# XtraReport text overflow cutting text in half vertically

Tags: xtrareport

I have an XtraReport that overflows text on to the next page but occasionally cuts the last line of text from the first page in half when it does.

I would normally handle this with the height property of the text area but I am unsure how to target a specific table row of an XtraReport to work out what the remaining height of the page is to achieve this or whether that would even work in this instance.

I'm rather hoping there's a simple work around to achieve this, **please don't go too much out of your way** to help out as I won't be investing much development on this.

[image]

I don't think there are any settings I have missed within the designer, perhaps there's a golden font size or line height that the reports want to overflow correctly.

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

If there is no simple way, I will just have to loop through the tr / td tags and see if by manipulating the height I can find that sweet spot, i just worry that it will hide page 1 but still be split on page 2.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you use the ASPx/MVCx -DocumentViewer,
this control shows you a html content which is not suitable for pixel-perfect documents.
I recommend you to try the ASPx/MVCx WebDocumentViewer which is like the the Google Docs shows pixel-perfect document and more convenient with bootstrap and other progressive web frameworks.

here are [demo](https://demos.devexpress.com/MVCxReportDemos/ComplexReports/FallCatalogReport) and [docs](https://documentation.devexpress.com/AspNet/114491/ASP-NET-MVC-Extensions/Report-Extensions/Document-Viewer/HTML5-Document-Viewer).

Comment: This sounds perfect! I will give that a try later today, we are a little out of sync with DevExpress features...

Comment: This has worked for the render on site, I have a few text blur issues to deal with and PDF export still does the text split. But it's the stepping stone I needed, thank you very much.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, your document looks different on the preview, than when exporting to pdf document (this can occur very rarely when using some fonts, so you can try to change your font). i recommend you to try the latest dxp version - the dx printing and dx pdf libraries are improved every minor release. you can give a try to a new version and check your report document on it.

Comment: and you wouldn't be wrong there... I'll give that a try, thank you.